# Java Copy Constructor Not Copying a Value

Tags: java, copy-constructor

I coded up a class which models a stock:

```
public Stock(String ticker, int shares, float purchasePrice) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if(ticker == null || ticker == "" ||
        shares <= 0 || purchasePrice <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(Messages.enterAppropriateValues());

    this.ticker = ticker;
    this.shares = shares;
    this.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    latestPrice = purchasePrice;
    updatePercentGain();
}
```

The copy-constructor looks like:

```
public Stock(Stock other) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    this(other.ticker, other.shares, other.purchasePrice);
}
```

Here are the commands I that used to test this:

```
    Stock bac = new Stock("BAC", 100, 42.22f);
    System.out.println(bac);

    bac.setLatestPrice(43.35f);
    System.out.println(bac);

    Stock bacCopy = new Stock(bac);
    System.out.println(bacCopy);
```

Output is:

```
    BAC 100 42.22 42.22 0.00%
    BAC 100 42.22 43.35 2.68%
    BAC 100 42.22 42.22 0.00%
```

For some reason, the last value which represents the **percent-gain** is not copying over?

Here's the percent-gain method btw:

```
public void updatePercentGain()
{
    percentGain = ((latestPrice - purchasePrice) / purchasePrice) * 100;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is wrong: `ticker == ""`, instead you want to use `ticker.equals("")`.

Comment: You can use "==" for strings. It works

Comment: How did this value of '43.35' get here? `BAC 80 42.22 43.35 2.68%`

Comment: It works if you're trying to see if the passed in string is the exact same local string instance declared inside the constructor which is of course impossible since it's *local* to the constructor. Use `equals` instead. Just because it compiles does not mean it's correct.

Comment: @mathisnotmyforte: It might *appear* to work, but it doesn't work in general.

Comment: you can use == for strings, but it will always return false unless it's the same instance... in other words, no, don't use == for strings, this is Java, not Scala or JavaScript...

Comment: Using `==` for `String`s is almost always wrong.  _Don't do it._

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll go back and replace "==" with .equals. @Cory, I added more code in my OP to show where that value came from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your `Stock` constructor runs, it initialises the `latestPrice` with the `purchasePrice` passed in to the constructor. Since these values are the same, the percent gain will be 0.00%.

If you wish to also copy the current `latestPrice` in your copy constructor, you'll have to do that too:

```
public Stock(Stock other) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    this(other.ticker, other.shares, other.purchasePrice);
    this.latestPrice = other.latestPrice;
    updatePercentGain();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your actual constructor (not your copy constructor), you are not copying over the latestPrice, you're just setting it equals to the current price:

```
latestPrice = purchasePrice;
```

So your copy constructor is only passing over "42.22" and not "43.35", and your copy doesn't get the latestPrice.